# What's the equivalent of Hide From Menus on MODX on WordPress?

Tags: custom-post-types, query

In MODX, there's a checkbox on posts that will hide it from the main navigation and the post query. This is a very good way of making the post private for reviewing or simply having the post accessible only if you know the link.

I'm using custom post types and I want to add custom fields to hide or unhide this post whenever I want to. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a Custom Field radio button called hide_from_menus with values **yes** or **no** t then use [Query posts by custom fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/).

Then in your query, add meta_key and meta_value. Example:

```
      $args=array(
        'post_type' => custom-post-type,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_key'    => 'hide_from_menus',
        'meta_value'  => 'yes' 
      );
```

Be sure though that you update all your posts (re-publish) so that it will have the key value that you specified.